# How do I get element related to active input in jQuery UI Autocomplete?

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to pass a custom form attribute (category) through jQuery UI Autocomplete to use in a product search. The form looks like `<form id="BulkOrderForm" category="samplecategory"><input></input>...</form>` and contains inputs that use the autocomplete script. There can be several forms on each page, so I need to be able to get the category value from the form that contains the active input field.

Here's my source:

```
function autocomplete() {
    $("input.wcbulkorderproduct").autocomplete({
        element: function(){
            var element = $('form#BulkOrderForm').attr('category');
            return element;
        },
        source: function(request, response, element){
            $.ajax({
                url: WCBulkOrder.url+'?callback=?&action='+acs_action+'&_wpnonce='+WCBulkOrder.search_products_nonce,
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term: request.term,
                    category: element
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Any thoughts on how this can be acheived?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you're trying to use the active `input`'s parent `form` in the ajax request. Here's a way to achieve that:

Html:

```
<form data-category="form1">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
</form>
<form data-category="formB">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('form').each(function () {
    var category = $(this).data('category');

    $(this).find('input').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            response([category]);
        }
    });
});
```

Instead of using autocomplete on a catch-all selector that gets `input`s from all `form`s, first select the `form`s themselves. For each one, extract the category, then select all child `input`s and call autocomplete on that result. Then you can use the `category` variable in the ajax call - in the example I'm simply passing it to the callback to display.

http://jsfiddle.net/Fw2QA/

Comment: +1 good solution. Although I don't know if the OP is willing to use the "data" functionality of jQuery. My opinion, is that is better to use it since putting attributes in the html and handling them by hand seems geeky, but can be exceptions.

Comment: Yeah, since either the attribute or the data method can be used to get the category, and the data method is the 'proper' HTML5 way to do it (even though there's not really a practical difference), I figured I'd throw that in there to pique the OP's curiosity :)

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you another solution, you can lookup the parent form of the active input, and extract the attribute from it. Because I don't know if this category in your form is dynamic or no, or either if you can control all of the process involved in your code, I'll give you a more generic solution, although if that attribute is dynamic "Turch" solution is way better than mine, by letting the `data` functionality of jquery handle the attribute changes, if it's static, than you can just do it like this:

```
function autocomplete() {
    var element = $("input.wcbulkorderproduct").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response){
            $.ajax({
                url: WCBulkOrder.url+'?callback=?&action='+acs_action+'&_wpnonce='+WCBulkOrder.search_products_nonce,
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term: request.term,
                    category: element
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        }
    }).parents('form').first().attr('category'); 

    //chained call, sets autocomplete, grabs the parent form and the attribute
    //which is saved on the variable element, and is used on every call through
    //javascript context inheritance.
}
```

**UPDATE**

A little example illustrating my suggestion (provided by @Turch > thanks), can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fw2QA/2/).

Comment: That would only work if there was one form, since all calls to `source` would reference the same `element` variable. Check out http://jsfiddle.net/Fw2QA/1/ - all inputs use 'formB'. You could still go bottom-up (look up form from element) instead of top-down (get forms, for each, get inputs) but it would need to be saved to a closed-over variable so that different inputs can use different values.

Comment: Here's a version that does that, with a .each() : http://jsfiddle.net/Fw2QA/2/ . Now there's a copy of the variable for each input's `source`

Comment: @Turch that's not correct. the call to source is called for each input, because he is setting the autocomplete onto an input directly based on ID. My code assumes the setup is made by id, your example is wrong (.../1), as it makes an incorrect assumption, by specifying a more generic selector!

Comment: @Turch, that's what I was going to say... If you want to simulate my solution, for more than one input field, then call $('input').each(function(){ //and use $(this) in the place of the $("input.wcbulkorderproduct") }); this is the solution I'm pointing to the OP.

Comment: Ah ok, your last comment cleared it up. Yeah that's totally a viable way as well (and that's what I did in the last .../2 fiddle ). Ed: comment editing yay :)

Comment: @Turch, yes off course, but because he posted just a function called autocomplete without arguments, I assumed he must be doing that kind of stuff somewhere in is code. I also took the liberty of updating my answer with your kind example, hope you don't mind. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's much appreciated. I went with Turch's answer because it worked right out of the box and Turch answered first. But, your answer works, at least for a single form! Looks like it would need to be modified a bit to work with multiple forms but I didn't have a chance to investigate that yet...